# Submenu not working properly on small screen in foundation 6 wordpress theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

I have this html generated by wordpress:

```
<li id="menu-item-843" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-843 is-dropdown-submenu-parent opens-left" role="menuitem" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Predjela i grickalice" data-is-click="false"><a href="http://localhost:8081/skuvajme/category/predjela-i-grickalice/">Predjela i grickalice</a>
<ul class="vertical menu float-left submenu is-dropdown-submenu first-sub" data-submenu="" aria-hidden="true" role="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-892" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-892 is-submenu-item is-dropdown-submenu-item" role="menuitem"><a href="http://localhost:8081/skuvajme/category/umaci-sosovi-dipovi-i-prelivi/">Umaci sosovi dipovi i prelivi</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

When shown on large+ screen it works fine, but when i resize browser to medium or small, submenu is folding outside of window.

I'm using [this](https://wlcdesigns.com/2015/11/foundation-6-menu-walker-class-for-wordpress/) tutorial to integrate menu in wordpress theme.

Here is [uploaded](http://onedevteam.com/wptest/) theme i'm working on.

Can someone help me solve this?